# Can't build Webrtc with Bitcode enabled

Tags: ios, webrtc, bitcode, webrtc-ios

I am trying to rebuild WebRTC iOS framework with Bitcode enabled but it's not working it's giving me errors. And the error messages are

> clang++: error: unknown argument: '-ffile-compilation-dir=.'

> clang++: error: -gdwarf-aranges is not supported with -fembed-bitcode

If I build it without bitcode enable true only then it's working. Can anyone have any idea why I am having this issue?
My Xcode version is 12.5.1

Comment: Same issue. didn't luck for me

Comment: @Jihan Having the same issue, did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

I used llvm12 to build webrtc on arm64 linux and encounter the same error
`clang++: error: unknown argument: '-ffile-compilation-dir=.'` at first.

In the `src/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn`, there are some setting  like below:

```
if (is_nacl) {
# TODO(https://crbug.com/1231236): Use -ffile-compilation-dir= here.
cflags += [
"-Xclang",
"-ffile-compilation-dir",
"-Xclang",
".",
]
} else {
# -ffile-compilation-dir is an alias for both -fdebug-compilation-dir=
# and -fcoverage-compilation-dir=.
cflags += [ "-ffile-compilation-dir=." ]
}
```

I replace all of the `-ffile-compilation-dir` into `-fdebug-compilation-dir` then it worked fine!

Comment: This one worked for me. I wonder if WebRTC team is going to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs due to the old version of clang in Xcode. I executed the script with the given arguments:

```
build_ios_libs.py --extra-gn-args 'use_xcode_clang=false enable_dsyms=true' --bitcode --arch device:arm64 simulator:x64
```

Inside the webRTC dist, there is a new version of the LLVM (clang) package that will build the correct framework!

Comment: arm64 simulator fails. It is needed for a MacBook on M1. This error was not defeated

Comment: By using this args, framework is created successfully for simulator and devices but when I try to add in demo project which is bitcode enabled throwing error for bitcode.

Comment: @MrugeshTank if you use firebase crashlitics. You can turn off bitcode and upload dSYMs files manually. It works for me https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios

Comment: webRTC framework uses llvm14, but xcode uses only llvm12. They are not compatible with each other, for this reason the framework is not built. Even the new version of xCode 13 beta 5 doesn't support building the webRTC framework because uses llvm 13 :(

Comment: So, there is no option for building bitcode enabled framework?

Comment: I'm using Firebase Crashlytics with Bitcode enabled. I need Bitcode to reduce app size for Download from AppStore. And that's why I need to build WebRTC with bitcode enabled

Comment: @MrugeshTank dSYMs files are not included in your application release. They are only needed to view crashes in firebase. These dSYMs files are stored in the archive of your application when you collect it for submission to the store. I was unable to build a framework with bitcode enabled

Comment: I forced to use clang 14 from "..../src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin" (via "sudo nano /etc/paths" adding this path on top) but I still get this error: clang++: error: "-mllvm is not supported with -fembed-bitcode"

Comment: @DanieleCeglia same here... in addition when I try to use the flag `use_xcode_clang=false` I'm getting this message

`The variable "use_xcode_clang" was set as a build argument
but never appeared in a declare_args() block in any buildfile.` 

and still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been addressed in top-of-tree chromium. According to this pull request, `use_xcode_clang` is being removed because top-of-tree clang supports `-fembed-bitcode`: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/6edcf847d80f13740e1a26a86d3b95a0bb9fbcad